# Как программно проскроллить вверх NestedScrollView внутри CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-material, coordinator-layout

У меня есть CoordinatorLayout внутри которого есть следующие элементы:

1. AppBarLayout внутри которого CollapsableToolbar;
2. NestedScrollView

Я хочу программно проскролить NestedScrollView наверх таким образом что бы Collapsable Toolbar схлопнулся.

Я пытался сделать это следующим кодом:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
if (behavior != null) {
    behavior.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, appBarLayout, nestedScrollView, 0, 1000, new int[2]);
}
```

Однако данный код скролит только сам AppBarLayout, а NestedScrollView не трогает.

Вопрос в том как правильно программно проскроллить NestedScrollView наверх, так что бы CollapsableToolbar сложился.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <!-- some content -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/quick_return_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <!-- some content -->

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Ха) Надеюсь то, что приведённым способом скролится только `AppBarLayout` - это не баг, а фича, ибо как раз последние пару дней ищу как скролить `AppBar` не трогая всё остальное)

Comment: По вопросу - тут смотрели: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31014409/3212712?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Смотрел, данный метод действительно скролит NestedScrollView, однако Tулбар стоит на месте

Comment: А вы оба способа из обоих ответов пробовали? А что, если совместить способ из вашего вопроса со способом из ссылки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31217896/3212712) предлагают такое решение:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBar.getLayoutParams();
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
if (behavior != null) {
     behavior.onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout, appBar, null, 0, 1000, true);
}
```

При использовании `true` в качестве последнего аргумента выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При использовании `false` в качестве последнего аргумента выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Чтобы проскролить только скроллящийся элемент и не трогать `AppBarLayout` надо просто вызвать `scrollBy(int x, int y)` на нём:

```
someScrolledConteiner.scrollBy(int x, int y);
```

Скроллить только `AppBarLayout`, не трогая остальное - как в вопросе:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
if (behavior != null) {
    behavior.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, appBarLayout, nestedScrollView, 0, 1000, new int[2]);
}
```