# Как сохранить состояние TextView? (UPD)

Tags: java, android, activity, textview, nested-scrollview

Имеется TextView с большим текстом, который прокручивается. Как сделать чтобы после поворота экрана/нового запуска приложения чтение продолжалось с того момента, где закончил?

UPD
Частично вопрос решен, после поворота экрана позиция текста с горем пополам сохраняется. Но после перезапуска приложения текст вновь начинается с начала. Обновил код.

```
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public TextView mText;
public NestedScrollView mNested;
private static final String TAG = "myLogs";

SharedPreferences sPref;

final String SAVED_POSITION = "saved_position";
final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    mNested = (NestedScrollView)findViewById(R.id.nested);

// По нажатию кнопки в Main Activity запускается Scrolling Activity с нужным   текстом и позицией 

    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i.getIntExtra("load",0) == 1){
        loadText();
    }

}

   public void saveText() {
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, mText.getText().toString());
    ed.putInt(SAVED_POSITION, mNested.getScrollY());
   Log.d(TAG,"method save text " + mNested.getScrollY());
    ed.apply();
}

   public void loadText() {
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
    final int savedPosition = sPref.getInt(SAVED_POSITION, 0);
    mText.setText(savedText);
    mNested.scrollTo(savedPosition,savedPosition);
   Log.d(TAG,"method load text " + savedPosition);

   }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBar.getLayoutParams();
    AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();

    System.out.println("restore getScrollY: " + savedInstanceState.getInt("pos"));

    if (behavior != null) {
        int pixelsToScroll = savedInstanceState.getInt("pos"); 
        behavior.onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout, appBar, null, 0, pixelsToScroll, true);
    }
    mNested.scrollTo(savedInstanceState.getInt("pos"),savedInstanceState.getInt("pos"));
    Log.d(TAG,"onRestore");
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt("pos", mNested.getScrollY());
    Log.d(TAG, "onSave");

}
   @Override
    protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG,"onStop");
        saveText();

}
```

//XML activity_scrolling

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.st18apps.modernetiquette4.ScrollingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/background"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync_noanim"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

//XML content_scrolling

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.st18apps.modernetiquette4.ScrollingActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling"
android:id="@+id/nested">

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:text="@string/common_rules"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#FF101010"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:freezesText="true"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Длинный текст в `TextView` лучше прокручивать не силами самого `TextView`, а поместив его в `ScrollView` и назначив ему высоту, равную высоте содержимого, т.е. `wrap_content`

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Теперь, если положение `TextView` внутри `ScrollView` не восстановится само, то надо будет его сохранить перед поворотом в методе `onSaveInstanceState`, восстановить в `onCreate` и промотать до сохранённого места:

1. Сохраняем:

   ```
   protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
   {

       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
       outState.putIntArray("SCROLL_POSITION", new int[] { scrollView.getScrollX(), scrollView.getScrollY() });

   }
   ```
2. Восстанавливаем в `onCreate` или `onRestoreInstanceState`:

   ```
   final int[] position = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("SCROLL_POSITION");
   ```
3. Прокручиваем до сохранённой позиции там же:

   ```
   if (position != null)
   {
       scrollView.post(new Runnable()
       {
           @Override
           public void run()
           {
               scrollView.scrollTo(position[0], position[1]);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

---

Для сохранения/восстановления после полного перезапуска приложения надо сохранять эти значения в `SharedPreferences`.

**UPD_0:**

Согласно вот этому моему [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468929/17609) в случае `NestedScrollView` в `CoordinatorLayout` и при ниличии `AppBarLayout` скроллить всё это надо как-то так:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBar.getLayoutParams();
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
if (behavior != null) {
     int pixelsToScroll = 1000; //надо заменить на сохранённое значение
     behavior.onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout, appBar, null, 0, pixelsToScroll, true);
}
```

Comment: TextView находится внутри NestedScrollView (из шаблона Scrolling Activity в Android Studio). В NestedScrollView не получается вызвать getScrollX(), getScrollY(). Менять Nested на простой ScrollView не вариант, тоже самое.

Comment: @Ivan, что значит "не получается"? Методы такие у `NestedScrollView` есть. `scrollTo` тоже есть. В чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: Android Studio ругается - "Non-static method 'getScrollX()' cannot be referenced from a static context." Пишу onSaveInstanceState перед onStop(). Что я делаю не так ? Android  знаю так себе, поэтому извиняюсь за возможно, глупые вопросы.

Comment: @Ivan, вы где-то зачем-то статические методы пользуете. В них нельзя нестатические методы вызывать. Ваш код не видно, точнее не сказать. onSaveInstanceState - это метод активити/фрагмента, его надо там ппереопределить и вызывать самому не надо - его автоматически вызовет система при пересоздании активити/фрагмента. Почитайте про жизненный цикл активити/фрагмента.

Comment: Добавил текст кода.

Comment: @Ivan, у `NestedScrollView` нема таких статических методов... Вам надо получить экземпляр `NestedScrollView` из разметки с помощью `findViewById`. Тот же принцип, что и с `TextView mText`

Comment: Всё сделал так, но ... состояние не сохраняется. После поворота экрана текст показывается с начала.

Comment: @Ivan, попробуйте тогда заменить NestedScrollView на ScrollView. У меня этот код работает для ScrollView. Возможно, для NestedScrollView надо несколько иначе. И добавьте разметку активити в вопрос.

Comment: Пробовал поместить TextView в ScrollView ( внутри NestedScrollView). Без результата.

Comment: @Ivan, не-не, я имел в виду убрать вообще NestedScrollView и вместо него ScrillView поставить

Comment: @Ivan, и `android:freezesText="true"` уберите, раз он всё одно не работает.

Comment: Пробовал так  <android.support.v4.widget.ScrollView> и так <ScrollView>, оба варианта  при запуске падают с ошибкой.

Comment: @Ivan, без указания того с какой ошибкой и на какой строке то, что падает с ошибкой ни о чём не говорит.

Comment: В случае <android.support.v4.widget.ScrollView> ошибка в строке  setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling)- не удается найти класс.  В случае <ScrollView> таки запустилось, но позицию все равно не запоминает, и appbar не уменьшается при скролле как раньше.

Comment: @Ivan, кажется я понял в чём дело. Добавьте в вопрос полную разметку активити. У вас там ведь и `CoordinatorLayout`, небось, есть?

Comment: Добавил  разметку. Всё как в шаблоне Scrolling Activity в Android Studio.

Comment: @Ivan, см. обновлённый ответ

Comment: Как я понял, в pixelsToScroll нужно занести текущую позицию по вертикали. Но как её достать? Пробовал getScrollY() в onSaveInstanceState() , ничего не меняется.

Comment: @Ivan, т.е getScrollY() в onSaveInstanceState всегда 0 возвращает?..

Comment: Я не знаю как определить, какое значение возвращает getScrollY(). Дело не в этом. Какое бы значение я не присваивал переменной pixelsToScroll - при перевороте текст всё равно начинается с начала. Ваш код из UPD_0 влияет только на appbar(запоминается свернут он или нет)

Comment: @Ivan, узнать что и кто возвращает можно просто выведя инфу в логи - `System.out.println("getScrollY: "+mNested.getScrollY());`. И у вас остался NestedScrollView или просто ScrollView?

Comment: Использую NestedScrollView. getScrollY() возвращает правильные значения(чем дальше прокручиваю текст - тем больше число). в onRestoreInstanceState пишу int pixelsToScroll = savedInstanceState.getInt("pos"). По логам сохраняется перед onStop(), восстанавливается перед onResume(), т.е. всё нормально. Но позиция текста не сохраняется :(

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33103/discussion-on-answer-by-----textview).

Comment: @Barmaley, ну можно и там, но сообразит ли ТС?.. =)

Answer (score 0):

У `TextView` есть атрибут [freezesText](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AfreezesText):

```
<TextView 
     ... 
     android:freezesText="true" />
```

Он вроде как раз это и делает.

Comment: Как это реализовать в коде? Пробовал onSaveInstanceState вызвать setFreezesText(), а в onRestoreInstanceState - getFreezexText() - ничего не поменялось.